# How to get data from _raw in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have this search query:

```
index="abc" |search SomeInfo | table _raw
```

and it returns table with results in one column in this format:

```
2020-09-10 15:57:24,479 [the_value_i_need] INFO  java.class.name:52 - SomeInfo|NAME=NAME1 
2020-09-10 16:57:33,479 [the_value_i_need] INFO  java.class.name:52 - SomeInfo|NAME=NAME1 
2020-09-10 17:58:24,479 [the_value_i_need] INFO  java.class.name:52 - SomeInfo|NAME=NAME1
```

Now, how do I get value "the_value_i_need" in square brackets[] and display it in the table instead of showing everything from _raw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you know the table is showing _raw because you told it to do so.  Replace "_raw" in the `table` command with other field names to display those fields.  With any luck, Splunk extracted several fields for you, but the chances are good it did not extract the one you want.  You can extract fields yourself using the `rex` command.

```
index="abc" "SomeInfo"
| rex "\[(?<fieldIneed>[^\]]+)"
| table fieldIneed
```